# Multilevel regression meta-analysis : no existing package? (Edited)

Tags: r, regression, multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis

The question is in the title.

**Meta-analysis with binomial distribution**

I'm trying to do a meta-analysis on occurence of an event across different studies. For each study $i$ ($i=1,\dots,N$), I have the number of participants $n_i$ and the number of events $k_i$. I don't have individual data. The number of event thus follows a binomial distribution: $k_i\sim Bin(\theta_i,n_i)$, where I assume a random effect: $\theta_i\sim N(\theta,\tau)$.

**Regression meta-analysis**

Additionally, I'm doing a regression on $\theta$ using the variable $x_i$: $$\theta_i\sim N(\alpha+\beta x_i,\tau).$$

**Multi-level regression meta-analysis**

Some studies are split into groups. As they have the same baseline characteristics, I thought of using a multi-level model (first formulation):
$$\theta_{i,j}\sim N(\alpha+\beta x_{i,j},\tau+\delta_j).$$
We could alternatively write it like this (although it is a bit different, second formulation):
$$\theta_{i}\sim N(\alpha+\beta x_i,\tau).$$
$$\theta_{i,j}\sim N(\theta_i+\gamma_i x_{ij},\delta_j)$$

**Which function to use in R**

I thought of doing it with the `rma.mv()` function from the `metareg` package, but the issue is that you cannot specify the distribution of the data. As far as I understood, it assumes normally distributed data. I thought of applying a logit transformation to the probability of success $p_i:=k_i/n_i$, but it's not possible to the some zero counts ($y_i=0$ for some studies i). Any other function that could solve that?
Moreover, I'm not sure if such models follow my first or second formulation.

Comment: Are the $\tau$ values known *a priori*?  Are groups at a lower level than studies (multiple groups per study) or a higher level? Your within-study specification seems odd - the mean doesn't differ with $j$, but the standard deviation does?  Are the $\delta_j$ known *a priori*?  Should the $\delta_j$ be treated as random effects?

Comment: $\theta_i\sim N(\theta,\tau)$ means $\theta_i$ can > 1 or <0.

Comment: You presumably mean to have the random effect on the logit of $theta_i$?

Comment: You can do this with `glmer()` from the `lme4` package, using `family=binomial`. Specify random effects as needed.